# Google Sheet: Get Data from NSE website to Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

I want to import data i.e. Issued Cap. and Free Float Market Cap. from this website:
Edit: 11-Jun-2022
https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=TRITURBINE
in Company information sector to a Google sheet.
I have tried `Importhtml`, `Importdata` and `Importxml`...but they all give an error or return #N/A.

Any suggestions would help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

import formulae of google sheets do not support the scrapping of JS elements. you can always test this by disabling JS on a given site and usually, what's left can be imported into a spreadsheet. in your case fields are blank:

[image]

Comment: Can we get data from https://www1.nseindia.com/marketinfo/companyTracker/compInfo.jsp?symbol=TRITURBINE&series=EQ Since it works even after disabling JS

Comment: @pk1978 still a nope. I even tried it directly within app-script but with no luck. got any other alternative?

Comment: I do not have any other alternative at present .. Will revert if I find one...

Comment: How about from below site [link](https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=TRITURBINE)

Comment: @pk1978 https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ7e7.png